# python: why is user script directory shared across python versions?

Tags: python, pep

From [PEP-370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/):

> user script directory
>
> A directory for binaries and scripts. [10] It's shared across Python versions and the destination directory for scripts.
>
> Unix (including Mac)
>
> ```
>   ~/.local/bin
> ```
>
> Windows
>
> ```
>   %APPDATA%/Python/Scripts
> ```

Why does it propose version-specific user site dirs but not user script dirs? Wouldn't scripts coming from different python versions conflict each other then?

Edit. Yes, they would. I did a test with `python2-pytest` and `python3-pytest`. When installing both into user dir with pip, one `pytest` script overwrote another without a warning.

There seems to be a relevant link but it's dead:

Discussion about the bin directory http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/91095

Comment: Because scripts are executables, just like other things in `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/local/bin`, etc.

Comment: Related: [Why did this program install into ~/.local/bin ... thats the first time I have seen that happen?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/240037)

Comment: You can edit scripts to use a specific python executable. Just change the shebang line at the top of the script. There could still be some library conflicts, though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Executable or not, you can still have version-specific dirs under `~/.local/bin` just like with `~/.local/lib`.

Comment: Basically, '.local/bin` is [part of the systemd home-dir filesystem spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html#Home%20Directory), so a good choice to put local binaries and commands. There is no provision for python-specific versions.

Comment: @HåkenLid: they already will use a specific Python version, that's not the point. Cyker is concerned about multiple Python versions with the same script.

Comment: Well. It's pretty common for python executable scripts to have `!# /usr/bin/env python` as shebang. That could resolve to different python versions when using virtual environments.

Comment: @HåkenLid: this is specifically about automated installs with `pip`, where `setup.py` console scripts entries are generated and will use a specific Python binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *shell* doesn't support per-Python-version binaries. There is a single namespace for command-line executables, the first name found in the directories listed on `PATH` is used.

The point of the `~/.local/bin` directory here is that it is added to the `PATH` environment variable, and that scripts and other executables are put there *for command line use*. And because there is only a single namespace for such executables, there is no point in putting commands into per-version directories here.

Instead, it is up to the project to provide you with versioned executables. The `pip` project uses [`setup.py` configuration](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/169cd10b3fe15747afc1ea5c582ff0cb3d2b8052/setup.py#L73-L79) to `pip`, `pipX` and `pipX.Y` scripts when installed with Python X.Y, and so you'll always have a more specific version of the script when there are multiple Python versions. And you can also use the module as a script with `pythonX.Y -m pip`. Lots of Python command-line tools have similar support.

As for the lost GMane link (still [available on the web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20121020055728/permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/91095)); there are other archives of the Python-dev discussion still available, such as [this grokbase.com rendering of the same post](https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-dev/081b29k17a/pep-per-user-site-packages-directory#20080114ufg3dqzr5juymhzbs5cv7i26v4); that discussion was about what directory to place the scripts in, `~/bin` or `~/.local/bin`, and was never about per-Python-version directories.

Comment: Comparing `~/.local/bin` with `/usr/bin` sounds valid. But `/usr/bin` is often managed by system package manager while `~/.local/bin` runs wild. I just tested with `python2-pytest` and `python3-pytest`. One `pytest` script does overwrite another without warning. So I think `pythonX.Y -m` is the rescue in such case. But considering other programs install into paths like `~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin`, it might be good if python some day uses a similar approach. There is no package manager for `~/.local/bin` anyway. It's better for users themselves to decide what are linked there.

Comment: You should compare `~/.local/bin` with `/usr/local/bin`, really, as both are outside of the system package manager responsibilities.  And Python has virtualenv and Pipenv to manage per-project dependencies, where Pipenv knows how to re-use virtualenvs as needed. That gives you similar behaviour as Gem does. It is not Ruby that creates those `~/.gem` directories, after all.

Comment: Yup that's more accurate, but `/usr/local/bin` usually has root permission so things are less likely messed up. `virtualenv` actually provides best isolation, but you have to activate before each use and that's terrible for commonly used commands. I'd better ignore `~/.local/bin` and go with `pythonX.Y -m` if a package is installed with multiple versions of python. Hopefully some day they would do `~/.python/X.Y.Z/bin`.

Comment: @Cyker: you don't have to activate a virtualenv. You can add the virtualenv-managed `/bin` directory to your path, or symlink the scripts into a directory that's on your path.

Comment: (And what Gem does is pick which `~/.gem/ruby/*/bin` directory is on your `PATH`, nothing more, which limits you to *one ruby version for all your tools*. Gem / Ruby made a different tradeoff from Python / virtualenv / Pipenv).